# Why UIScrollView's frame won't affected by constraints?

Tags: ios, uiscrollview

So I got this UIScrollView that had height constraint to a constant and width constraint to root view's width, but when I set a breakpoint in viewWillAppear(), I found that UIScrollView's width didn't change at all no matter what kind of phone(5s, 7 and 7 Plus) I tested on.

I read that UIScrollView doesn't been affected by constraints, but why this is the case?

[StoryBoard](https://i.stack.imgur.com/WIZBV.png)
[Variable Watcher](https://i.stack.imgur.com/rGJtH.png)
*Notice that I'm running on iPhoneSE but the width of imageScrollView is 414, which is iPhone 7 Plus's screen's width.

Comment: what you read is not correct. Show some code or the storyboard. Also, set the background colour of the scroll view to see how it is being laid out.

Comment: Hey! I uploaded both storyboard and variable watcher's screenshot.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

To the best of my understanding, what happens is, the view is loaded, then the new container view size is applied, after which constraints are re-calculated and subviews are re-laid out, however, when each of those steps takes place is a little opaque.

In my experience, the correct sizes are in place when viewDidAppear() is called, but in either viewDidLoad() viewWillAppear() you get the "design-time" sizes from the Interface Builder. didLayoutSubviews() is, also a possibility but keep in mind that it could be called multiple times throughout the life of the view controller.

The "correct" way would be to use Autolayout throughout (there is a [Technical Note](https://developer.apple.com/library/content/technotes/tn2154/_index.html) on using Autolayout with UIScrollView), however, it can be a bit tedious. For the less patient, one could apply sizes by setting a frame on the container view and calling updateConstraintsIfNeeded() and layoutIfNeeded() or you can guess the final sizes of elements based on the UIWindow size (see UIView.window or UIApplication.keyWindow) of the bounds of the parent view controller's view.

Good luck!